# How to translate the adjective "custom"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the Esperanto term for the adjective "[custom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/custom#Adjective)", i.e. made/designed (only) for a specific purpose or customer?

(In the meaning of "[custom-made](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/custom-made#English)", not in its other and maybe older contrary meaning of "accustomed"/"usual".)

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question, but I figured I'd add this as a comment anyway for other people coming across this question looking for another sense of the word "custom", i.e. customized to one's own preferences (not necessarily a customer ordering something). This could be used in (video) games, for example, when you use custom settings for a match. I find this is often called *laŭplaĉa*, and to customize in that sense, *laŭplaĉigi*.

Comment: The use-case that triggered that question for me probably needs some context, so I've asked a [new, more specific question](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5406/1576).

Answer (score 3):

According to [Vikivortaro](https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aldono:Vortaro_angla-Esperanto_c): **laŭmenda**.

Comment: Same suggestion from J.C.Wells' _Esperanto Dictionary_

Comment: Can that also be used when there was no order involved, or the order didn't specify the customization in question?

Answer (score -1):

Personecigita.

personecigi: Variigi laŭ la koncernataj personoj.

Comment: This would make a translation for "personalised" but for me *custom* as in the question is different from that.

Comment: The OP said "made/designed only for a specific customer". It does sound like personalized to me. But given it's about just customers, maybe tajlorita is better.