# How to translate "custom" in "custom file formats", referring to various rich-text formats?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

How should "custom" in the following [section from the Django Girls tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/code_editor/#why-are-we-installing-a-code-editor) be translated to Esperanto?

> ### Why are we installing a code editor?
>
> You might be wondering why we are installing this special code editor
> software, rather than using something like Word or Notepad.
>
> The first reason is that code needs to be **plain text**, and the problem
> with programs like Word and Textedit is that they don't actually
> produce plain text, they produce rich text (with fonts and
> formatting), using custom formats like [RTF (Rich Text Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).
>
> The second reason is that code editors are specialized for editing
> code, so they can provide helpful features like highlighting code with
> color according to its meaning, or automatically closing quotes for
> you.
>
> [...]

[This answer](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/5405/1576) to [How to translate the adjective "custom"?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/q/5404/1576) suggests *laŭmenda* as a translation for "custom", but I feel like that won't do here, as I don't know whether any rich texts formats (be they RTF or others) were made to any order.

In my [current translation attempt](https://crowdin.com/translate/django-girls-tutorial/294/en-eo#13342), I've gone for *tajlorita*:

> ### Kial instalu kodredaktilon?
>
> Vi eble scivolas, kial ni instalas tion speciala kodredaktila
> programaro anstataŭ uzi iel kiel Vordo (angle: Microsoft Word) aŭ
> Notepado (angle: Notepad).
>
> La unua kialo estas, ke kodo devas esti **pura teksto**, kaj la problemo
> de programoj kiel Vordo kaj TekstEdito (angle: TextEdit) estas, ke ili
> ne vere faras puran tekston. Ili faras riĉan tekston (kun tiparo kaj
> formatado), uzante tajloritajn formatojn kiel [RTF (Riĉtekstformato,
> angle: Rich Text Format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format).
>
> La dua kialo estas, ke kodredaktiloj estas speciale farita por redakti
> kodon, do ili havas helpemajn funkciojn kiel markadigi kodon kun
> koloroj laŭ ĝia signifo aŭ aŭtomate fermi citilojn por vi.

Is that a good choice? Are there better ones?

Comment: Is .rtf really a *custom* file format? I would think that custom file formats are restricted to one purpose or perhaps just one software program in which case "custom" means that it was created for that specific and limited usage.

Comment: Yeah, I wondered about that, too. Do you think the English original should be changed? I guess it might use "custom" here to contrast it to plain text that works with various plain-text-capable applications, whereas rich text formats, such as RTF or `.docx` only work with a more limited selection of applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tajlorita` is fine. I would tend to `propra` (`propre difinita`) though there is the following weakness:

```
custom = propra
customize = adapti / krei propran
```